# What is this antique wood object? Approx 10" long

Tags: wood

[image: Image2]What is this antique wood object?

[image: Image1]

Comment: It looks like a part of something, possibly a part of a machine. But it's possible you'll only get guesswork here, and even a correct guess may not be enough to firmly identify the source (there being similar parts in different machines that use similar mechanisms, so this could be generic). FWIW it seems it was partly hewn with an axe, a v. old technique that largely died out in the 20th century as a general woodworking practice but something that was retained in some places to the present day, so it could be from the 1990s as easily as the 1890s as far as that goes.

Comment: "What is this antique wood object? Approx 10" long"  -   I get that question every morning from the Alaska Woman. ( AKA, The Mrs.  )